# SSL Configuration of java adapter deployed on bluemix and compose mongodb

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have a Java adapter that we use to query a mongodb database and serve JSON responses to clients.

When deployed to a local server trying to query a compose mongodb on bluemix we naturally get the `SSLHandshakeException`, this was solved by manually importing the certificate provided by compose mongodb to our local mobilefirst keystore as the thrown exception suggested using keytool:

```
mfp-server\usr\servers\mfp\resources\security\key.jks
```

Creating a keystore through the mfp UI console did not solve this issue as the documentation suggests.

However we are perplexed to how to do the same on the mobile foundation deployed on bluemix.

We tried adding the keystore through the interface, creating a connectivity policy in the adapter descriptor file and using `System` properties in the jaxrs application class.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystorefile").getPath());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "keystorepassword");
```

None works so far, same for the local instance, updating `key.jks` is the only way we got the mfserver and composeMongoDB to work.

We are using MobileFirst 8 and a mongodb java driver version 3.2.2

And we're using this command to import compose's certificate to the self signed one we created:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore  <keystore name> -file <certificate_file_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen) and the writing some code to programmatically add the compose key to the truststore:

```
public static final String SSL_TRUST_STORE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "javax.net.ssl.trustStore";
public static final String SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD_SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword";

private String certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" +
                             "..." + 
                             "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

static {
    DefaultTrustStoreAppender trustStoreAppender = new DefaultTrustStoreAppender();
    final TrustStoreInfo trustStoreInfo = trustStoreAppender.append(CertificateFactory.newInstance(certificate));
    System.setProperty(SSL_TRUST_STORE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, trustStoreInfo.getTrustStorefFile().getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty(SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, trustStoreInfo.getPassword());
}
```

You would need this in your pom.xml (or alternative):

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com </url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
       <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orange.clara.cloud.boot.ssl-truststore-gen</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```